# Get the part of the string matched by regex

Tags: python, regex, search

In the case of `re.search()`, is there a way I can get hold of just the part of input string that matches the regex? i.e. I just want the `"heeehe"` part and not the stuff that comes before it:

```
>>> s = "i got away with it, heeehe"
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search("he*he", s)
>>> match.string
'i got away with it, heeehe'
>>> match.?
'heeehe'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`match.group(0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) is the matched string.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "i got away with it, heeehe"
>>> match = re.search("he*he", s)
>>> match.group(0)
'heeehe'
```

You can also omit the argument, `0` is the default.